# I run flutter doctor but it come up with error "pub get failed" what are the possible solution for this

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pub.dev

I run `flutter doctor` but it come up with the error "pub get failed". What is the possible solution for this? I download the latest Flutter version and it failed. I use Flutter version `3.7.10` and had no results.

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific on the issue itself. What does `flutter doctor` print exactly, also what is your OS?

Comment: -pub get failed(69) during running flutter doctor. i'm using windows

Comment: I have been trying to install the latest version of flutter but it failed.what is the best possible solution